# How to run an executable text-file directly?

Tags: linux-mint, netbeans, links, binary-files

I downloaded Apache Netbeans 11.0 (incubating) on Linux Mint 19.1.

Since it does not have an installer, i had to use it straight from binaries that came with the bin.zip.

Everything worked as they should, but i don't want to run it from terminal or go to the binary folder everytime, so i created a link "Netbeans" to it and placed it on the Desktop.

The link works too, but when clicking it, there's a pop-up window that asks if i want to see the contents or run the file. I want it to run automatically, without choosing "Run"-option from the pop-up window.

I tried `chmod 755 Netbeans` on the link file, but it didn't do anything, i checked and it already is an executable file, but i don't want that pop-up to happen. I want the Netbeans IDE open after clicking the link.

Is there any way to bypass the "See contents or execute" -window and just execute the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a link to the executable, but create a so called "Desktop Entry",
i.e. a simple `.desktop` file which your system interprets as a series of instructions to correctly load the application.

In your specific case, you should

1. Create (if not already present) the directory `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`;
2. Create inside it a new `Netbeans.desktop` file with the following content

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Netbeans
   Comment=Netbeans IDE
   Exec=** put here your full Netbeans executable path here **
   Icon=netbeans
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Development,IDE;
   StartupNotify=false
   ```
3. You'll find the Netbeans launcher in your application menu.

Obviously, you can/should modify the file content to your needs.

As for the meaning of the file entries, you can find [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1504) a nice tutorial for Linux Mint and [here](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) the official GNOME documentation on desktop entries.

Comment: I did all that but it did not show in application menu so i created a link for the Netbeans.desktop file and it worked like that.

Comment: Actually, i managed to find how to do this the "right" way. In the mouse right-click context menu, there was "Create new launcher" and it just asked for name and command to run and optionally an icon. I created a Netbeans launcher with that and it worked too.